# While connecting to Mongoose, i specified custom port: 5000, but output: Server running on port: ${PORT}

Tags: node.js, react-fullstack

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology:true })
.then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server running on port: ${PORT}'))) 
.catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Output:

```
Server running on port: ${PORT}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is running on `PORT` but the syntax you used to `console.log` is called [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

So it will be **`**(backtick) instead of `'`(quote).

```
.then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`)))
```

Comment: Is it worth mentioning in words too that this is backtick rather than single-quote?